# Encoding / Serializing TTF Font file to NSData

Tags: ios, serialization, core-text, uifont

I’m trying to use mattt’s `UIFontSerialization` class ([here](https://github.com/mattt/UIFontSerialization%20%E2%80%9Chere%22)) to convert some `UIFont` objects to `NSData`, to be able to serialize them and persist them in a CoreData or Realm database, but I’m getting the idea that it’s not going to do what I need.

I’m trying to serialize the `ttf` files themselves (which I receive from an API), so that I don’t need to store them in the user’s Documents directory or wherever. The idea is that my database stores everything it needs to render the font.

I’m running into a wall when using `CTFontCopyTable` to convert the `CTFontRef` into a `CFDataRef`. I’m doing this:

```
UIFont *originalFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Geometos" size:48];
CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)originalFont.fontName, originalFont.pointSize, NULL);
CFDataRef dataRef = CTFontCopyTable(fontRef, kCTFontTableCFF, kCTFontTableOptionNoOptions);
NSData *encodedFont = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)dataRef;
```

The `originalFont` is fine, in my bundle, displays in a label, etc. The `fontRef` is created properly too, no worries there. The `dataRef` ends up as nil. If I switch the table tag from `CFF` to something else, it’ll encode, but later when I come to decode it back to a `UIFont`, it’ll fail, so I think I need to use the `CFF` table (I have no idea what CFF stands for).

Anyone ever done this? Stored fonts as serialized data?

Comment: Hey did have you managed to find a way to encode the font with `CTFontCopyTable()` and `kCTFontTableCFF`? I'm running into this problem right now and can't seem to get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I’ve managed to get this working, integrated with a Realm database, and it’s pretty snappy!

In a nutshell, I fetch the `ttf` from my API, store the raw data from the response as `NSData` in my Realm database, retrieve it, then use the following method to convert it to a `UIFont` instance:

```
- (UIFont *)fontWithData:(NSData *)data size:(CGFloat)size {
    NSDate *before = [NSDate date];
    [UIFont familyNames]; // This prevents a known crash in CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData 
    CGDataProviderRef fontDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
    CGFontRef newFont = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(fontDataProvider);
    NSString *newFontName = (__bridge NSString *)CGFontCopyPostScriptName(newFont);
    CGDataProviderRelease(fontDataProvider);
    CFErrorRef error;
    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(newFont, &error);
    CGFontRelease(newFont);
    self.timeTakenToConvert = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:before];
    return [UIFont fontWithName:newFontName size:size];
}
```

Thought it was doable! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can store **fontName** and **fontSize** in database and after fetch from database create `NSFont` using those values.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
```

Comment: I’m trying to serialize the font itself, not just a reference to its name and size, sorry if that wasn’t clear. The idea is that I receive a TTF font from my API and then can then serialize them and store them, decoding them if the user selects that font.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
UIFont *originalFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:48];//Geometos
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:originalFont];
NSFont *font = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
NSLog(@"font:%@",font);
```

Comment: Right, but if I remove Arial from the phone, I can’t reconstruct the font from that data, can I? That’s what I’m trying to do.

Comment: do you check,  originalFont  return nil value? then how you get font value true?

Comment: would you please provide font table

Comment: It isn’t building the table, there’s nothing to provide I’m afraid – that’s the problem :)